# spring batch making flatfilereader support three different tokenizers for the same datafile

Tags: spring-batch

if a single fixed width ascii text file has records in three different fixed witdth formats, does spring batch org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader has a mechanism to map three different type of tokenizers to the same data file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer`.  It allows you to map a regular expression to a `LineTokenizer` implementation.  You can read more about the `PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer.html